# Getting url of a page once making a form submission

Tags: c#, asp.net, watin

I am designing a winforms based testing app (which is based upon WatiN). I specify a page to test and the value to insert into a textbox, and then click the corresponding button.

Is it possible to add a query string to the request I make (when clicking button) and then get the URL of the next page? Based on this, I need to screen scrape it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Watin syntax, but in Watir (Ruby version) you can get URL of the page displayed in browser with

```
browser.url
```

Or do you need to get URL of the next page before you open it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to AmitK, Željko's answer is right. 
In WatiN (and C#), the syntax is:

```
Console.WriteLine("The current page is:" + ie.Url.ToString());
```

(just in case: 'ie' is the browser reference, use whatever object you use to enter text and click buttons)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "next page" ? Does the form when submitted redirect to another page? If so, you will receive a HTTP 302/303 status code with the URL of the next page.

Comment: What I basically mean is when clicking a button and the new page the button points to loads, how can I get the url of that page through WatiN?